# what books do you suggest for a beginner like me ?

Tags: mobile-robot

i am studying bacholar of dental surgery but have intrest in learning this subjet so tell me about a good book to read.

Comment: Toppsy and Tim go to the Dentist : http://www.ebay.co.uk/itm/like/391404344515?lpid=122&chn=ps&googleloc=1006898&poi=&campaignid=620794543&device=c&adgroupid=27377119746&rlsatarget=pla-181479841746&adtype=pla&crdt=0

Comment: Welcome to *Robotics* immortalbeing, but I'm afraid that *Life Questions* are off-topic. Questions about how to spend your time (**what book to read**, which class to take, what robotics project to construct, what career to pursue, etc.) may be about difficult decisions, & they are often important, but they are too specific to your own situation & are unlikely to help future visitors to the site. They would be better off asked in [chat]. We prefer *[practical, answerable questions based on actual problems that you face](http://robotics.stackexchange.com/help/dont-ask)*, see [ask] & [about].

Comment: If you have something specific you want to learn about, then come to [chat] and we can point you to some good resources.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you only want a single comprehensive text on Robotics, I would recommend the Springer *Handbook of Robotics*. I covers everything from controls and artificial intelligence to perception and mechanics; it is a phenomenal touchstone for further reading and is authored by the best minds in each sub-discipline in robotics. Of particular relevance to your background, there is significant coverage given to medical robotics, which you might find interesting.

Answer (score 0):

Most introduction courses which are held on schools and universities are practical oriented. They use out-of-box robotics sets like Lego Mindstorms, Aldebaran Nao or Baxter Robot. On the topics of robotics there are many good books out there for theoretical advice. Most dominant is "Artificial Intelligence: A Modern Approach". A nice ressource for additional information is Google Scholar. At the beginning i would suggest to search for paper which are using computergames like Mario AI or Starcraft AI for implementing algorithms.

Comment: Welcome to *Robotics*, ManuelRodriguez. On Stack Exchange we are are looking for comprehensive answers that provide some explanation and context. One-line answers cannot do this, so please edit your answer to explain why it is right, ideally with citations. Answers that don't include explanations may be removed.

Comment: Hey Manuel thanks for adding more information. I approved the edit to your post, which usually wouldn't be necessary: you can always edit your own content without approval. However, it looks like you have created a second account with the same name ([Manuel 1](http://robotics.stackexchange.com/users/14275/manuel-rodriguez) & [Manuel 2](http://robotics.stackexchange.com/users/14276/manuel-rodriguez)) thus you are considered a new user making the edit. Did you do this intentionally or by accident? Do you need help? It's possible to merge both accounts into one if you wish.Ask @Chuck or on [meta]

Comment: It looks like Manuel Rodriguez may have accidentally created two accounts. If so, then please follow the instructions at [I accidentally created two accounts; how do I merge them?](http://robotics.stackexchange.com/help/merging-accounts) Stack Exchange only allows an individual to actively use one account. Any and all duplicates should be merged into your main account. @BendingUnit22 - I can't personally merge the accounts, it [has to be request by the user](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/272251)

Comment: Note that while moderators [can't merge accounts for you](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/272251), they  may delete accounts they believe to be [sock puppets](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/57685/138432), so it would be better to [merge the accounts](http://robotics.stackexchange.com/help/merging-accounts) rather than risk account deletion, especially since your older account has some reputation to transfer to the newer one.